# how to change input in a pretrained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to change the input of the pertained `VGGFACe` model from `224x224x3` to `64x64x3` the model contains pertained weights is that possible to change it directly.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1),input_shape=(224,224, 3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
 
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
 
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
 
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
 
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1,1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))
 
model.add(Convolution2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Convolution2D(4096, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Convolution2D(2622, (1, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

from keras.models import model_from_json
model.load_weights('vgg_face_weights.h5')
```

this error come when I change directly the input size

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 7 from 2 for 'sequential_1/conv2d_14/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [0,2,2,512], [7,7,512,4096].
```

the code is from  https://sefiks.com/2018/08/06/deep-face-recognition-with-keras/

Answer (score 0):

The last max-pooling layer brings your initial image to a 2x2 size. You want then to apply a convolution with a kernel of 7x7 on your image, which is impossible.

The solution to this is to either leave the initial dimension of the images with which the network was trained (224x224) (i.e. to bring your images to that dimension) or to change the configuration of the neural network in order to avoid such dimensionality reduction problem.

Comment: thanks for your comment how can I change the configuration can you explain which part I can modify to get a 64x64x3 input

Comment: That is the problem, if you put a 64x64x3 input you will not be able to make the neural network run on such a dimension. Upsample/upscale your photos to 224x224 as a first step. Another solution would be to delete the two Convolution2D(4096) and Convolution2D(2622) and leave only the Flatten layer with the Softmax Activation.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you resize your 64x64x3 sized image to 224x224x3?

```
import cv2
img1 = cv2.imread("img1.jpg") #this is 64x64
img1_resized= cv2.resize(img1, (224, 224))
```

Then you can pass img1_resized to VGG-Face model.